# Win7 to WinXP Persistent Shared Drive getting disconnected

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, shared-folders

I originally posted this in [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) but was deemed off-topic so I'm posting this on here...

I'm currently experiencing an issue relating to shared drives between Windows 7 and Windows XP machines in our business and I seem to be at a loss as to why it's occurring... Let me provide a brief explanation of the network configuration and the issue I am trying to deal with;

In one environment in the business we have a number of users, each with a Windows 7 machine (**PC1**) and a Windows XP machine (**PC2**). **PC1** has a ***persistent*** network drive connection to **PC2** and this drive is used to allow other customer-facing Windows 7 machines to [circumnavigate the concurrent connection limit of Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314882) and transfer files to **PC2** by pushing their files to **PC1** through series of bespoke programs. Currently we are getting about 15-20 users a week complaining that the shared drive is becoming disconnected and it is impacting their work.

There are some scenarios that we have already identified that would cause **PC1** to drop the network drive connection (i.e. if the user locks their AD account on **PC1** (**PC2** is on a Workgroup), if the user reboots either computer or if they log out of **PC1**) but we are still getting calls about this problem unrelated to any of the scenarios mentioned previously.

The drive is initially mapped through a batch file in an EXE wrapper which runs at Startup and follows the below logic;

1. Clear all network drive shares
2. Check for flag file in C:\Windows\System32 (sometimes there can be two Win XP machines to map to; the flag is used to differentiate)
3. Use `net use [devicename] [sharename] /persistent:yes` to create the connection.

After investigating reasons for why the drive may become disconnected, I stumbled upon [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/297684) Microsoft article which describes the "autodisconnect" registry key that can de-activate a shared drive after a period of time. Using `net config server` to interrogate these values on the two computers yielded the following data;

**PC1**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>net config server
Server Name                           \\PC1
Server Comment                        

Software version                      Windows 7 Professional
Server is active on

//details removed    

Server hidden                         No
Maximum Logged On Users               20
Maximum open files per session        16384

Idle session time (min)               15
The command completed successfully.
```

**PC2**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\PC2_User>net config server
Server Name                           \\PC2
Server Comment                        

Software version                      Windows 2002
Server is active on

//details removed

Server hidden                         No
Maximum Logged On Users               10
Maximum open files per session        16384

Idle session time (min)               15
The command completed successfully.
```

Both computers have a default setting on the Idle session time, but the drive connection is persistent so this shouldn't affect it... right?

Additionally, when the user calls in to report this issue, I use RDP to connect to **PC1** and what I have noticed is that when you click on the drive share in Windows Explorer, a Username/Password prompt appears advising that the user account details are wrong but I know that this is not the case. The user account details are supplied by the mapping program and the AD account used to do this is not locked - furthermore, if you re-run the mapping program then the share maps correctly.

Event logs on **PC1** yield next to no information relating to this (at least as far as I can see) so I'm kind of stuck here - speaking to other people in the business, their advice has been to just write a program to check the drive connection periodically but I **need** to know what is causing this, if not for anything but my sanity!

My first question is this - Could the idle session timeout be the root cause? And more to the point, does the idle session time rule still apply if a shared drive connection is persistent? I cannot find an answer (or even a question of this kind) anywhere and my Google searches have turned up empty.

Secondly, are mapped drive details logged in the Event Logs at all? If I could see what was happening at the time of disconnection then this would greatly improve the chances of me fixing this issue.

Failing both of those, any suggestions, support or a reason why this is occurring would be greatly appreciated :P

Comment: Do the clocks (time and date) on all the computers match?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, yes they do. **PC1** has it's time synchronised by the DC, **PC2** has it's time synchronising via NTP (as far as I am aware) and the other Win7 devices get their time by querying a Tomcat Server running on **PC1**. Would time mismatching cause such a problem?